# Laravel 5 - Composite key indexes in migrations

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Composite indexes are a subject I'm not fully experienced in, I wasn't sure if I was doing it right? Or if Laravel is parsing my code correctly when migrating. Does this look correct?

```
Schema::create('friends', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('requester_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('requestee_id')->unsigned();
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('requester_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->foreign('requestee_id')->references('id')->on('users');

    $table->unique(['requester_id', 'requestee_id'], 'composite_index');
});
```

Here is what Sequel Pro shows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUytA.png

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you have there is correct.

---

**Note**: you don't *have* to specify the index's name. Laravel will automatically generate a name for you based on the columns being indexed.

Comment: Thanks, I indexed the name just so it was easier to understand in the picture.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my example: creating unique `external_id` for every user `user_id`:

```
    Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');

        $table->string('external_id')->nullable();
        $table->unique(['external_id', 'user_id']); // <<---------

        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

        // ...
    });
```